# ALAssetsLibrary resultBlock weak or strong reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference, xcode5, objective-c-blocks

For the call

```
[library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){...}
```

If I am to pass the image to an ImageView, should I pass the ImageView with a weak reference or should it be a strong reference? Can I ever go wrong with passing a weak reference? By weak reference I mean

```
__weak MyVC *weakSelf = self; 
....
weakSelf.myImageView...
```

Answer (score -1):

Block retains the object they reference and in turn will create a retain cycle. In your above code snippet, the block creates the retain cycle, you need to use weak reference to break the retain cycle as

```
 __weak typeof(self) *weakself = self;
```

or you can also implement it in following way

```
__block MyVC *blockSelf = self;
```

and reference the blockSelf inside the block.

This avoids the cycle, because blockSelf is not retained

Comment: where do you see a retain cycle?

Comment: As per my understanding, the retain cycle occurs when you reference self.myImageView inside the block as you're referring to self which will retain the self here and self itself retained the library as it is an ivar.

Comment: 1) you're assuming `self` retains the library, and 2) you're assuming that `library` retains the block passed to `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:`. The second assumption is highly unlikely, because if an `ALAssetLibrary` used an instance variable to store this, that would mean you cannot do two requests at the same time, which is not true.